# update media control class javafx

Tags: javafx, media-player, borderpane

I'm using the class from the following page: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm

I have a class called song which keep track of my mediaPlayers, I want to make it so that when I change the song in a playlist the player control does as well. i've tried reinitializing it to no avail, I use the player control class in my application at the bottom of a `BorderPane`. I have a progress listener currently that changes when the song changes, and I attempt to reinitialize my player control there but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try [MediaPlayerFX project](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/MediaPlayerFX/). Though the code is old and very badly written, it will still give you an idea on how things work :)

Comment: See the answer to [Playing audio using JavaFX MediaPlayer in a normal Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548603/playing-audio-using-javafx-mediaplayer-in-a-normal-java-application), it's a little over-complicated because it the question asks for a Swing wrapper, but it would be easy to adapt it to a pure JavaFX application.  I think the answer demonstrates the aspects you are looking for of updating the the player controls to reflect progress playing different media files.